# IOS css overflow property and vue3 not working

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I am currently working on a web development (Vue3) project, and it should be responsive.
I don't want to have a horizontal scroll at **all**.

I applied the overflow-x on the body, which works on android and desktop, but on IOS, I have a horizontal scroll.

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

code: https://github.com/OriGuyUniqueDev/davidmalkauiux
live demo site: https://davidmalkauiux.netlify.app/

How can I disable horizontal scroll on IOS devices?

Comment: `html, body { overflow-x: hidden;}`

Comment: I already tried it, and it didn't work, but thanks